# In which manner zeroMQ read form multiple connections?

Tags: zeromq

I want to know in which manner zeroMQ read form multiple connections ?

For example:

- If I have a server which is connected to multiple clients and receiving data at the same time from all the clients which of the one it will read first?
- Is it round robin or some other algorithm?

Comment: You are considering a pub-sub mechanism?

Comment: pub-sub and push-pull

Comment: Have you read [ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all)? In pub-sub each subscriber gets message. In push-pull we have 3 parts (publisher/ventilator, worker and sink) and sending data works like round robin. Maybe I did not understand your question or maybe you're just confused, it would be better if you would be more specific or post some code example. Also take a look at [The Load Balancing Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Load-Balancing-Pattern) part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pub-sub routine, Python example:

```
#Publishing script
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context()
socket_publish = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket_publish.bind("tcp://*:7787") #define socket for publishing

#subscribing script(s)
ctx = zmq.Context()
s = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
s.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:7787") #connect to the socket multiple times
s.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'')
msg  = s.recv()
```